# How Disk size in "System settings -> Details -> Disk" is calculated

Tags: partitioning, kernel, hard-drive

Can you please tell which node is used to get Disk size in  "System settings -> Details -> Disk".

In my system:

"System settings -> Details -> Disk" value is : 974.1 GB.

But below commands give different value:

1. `lshw -C disk` -> size = 931 GiB
2. `lsblk` -> sda size = 931.5 G
3. `fd -h` -> /dev/sda1 = 908 G

My system:

```
# uname -a
Linux sumitg-ubuntu 3.2.0-106-generic #147-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 21:27:24 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Can you please share sysfs node or formula which is used to print value in "System settings -> Details -> Disk".

Answer (score 0):

GB an GiB are two different units of measurement. 1 GB=1000 MB, but 1 GiB=1024 MiB, the same with MB vs MiB. That being said, some of the disk space is reserved for file system metadata. Some programs/utilities include this reserved space, some don't, also some (might) round up when transforming bits to GiB, some (might) round down, etc,

Comment: Thankyou for your comments. I am actually looking for the sysfs node or formula which is used to print value in "System settings -> Details -> Disk".